# DC.js geoChoroplethChart doesn't display anything

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to render a map of Australian data with an Australian map using dc.js geoChoroplethChart. Unfortunately the map is not showing at all.

```
 var nationalMap = dc.geoChoroplethChart("#national-map")
     .projection(projection)
     .width(900)
     .height(400)
     .transitionDuration(1000)
     .dimension(regionDimension)
     .group(regionGrouping)
     .filterHandler(function(dimension, filter) {
         dimension.filter(function(d) {
             return nationalMap.filter() != null ? d.indexOf(nationalMap.filter()) >= 0 : true;
         }); // perform filtering
         return filter; // return the actual filter value
     })
     .overlayGeoJson(aus, "regions", function(d) {
          return d.properties.STATE_ABBR + "1";
     })
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/trickidicki/mokmjhuo/

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed the problem - I hadn't specified the JSON selector on the GeoJSON file. Changing it to aus["features"] works.

Comment: Thanks for following up.